# Random walk on a Sierpinski gasket

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, random, fractals

I am trying to simulate a random walk on a Sierpinski gasket. The best strategy i could come up with is to use Nearest point function to determine the next possible step of my walker. But this creates an issue at n = 2 generation where the are two unwanted steps the walker shouldn't be able to go to. In other words, it shouldn't be able to cross the white triangle in the middle. There should always be 4 possible steps (except for the corners where there is only 2). Any ideas on how this case can be handled?

[image]

```
sierpinski[{a_, b_, c_}] := With[{ab = (a + b)/2, bc = (b + c)/2, 
ca = (a + c)/2}, {{a, ab, ca}, {ab, b, bc}, {ca, bc, c}}];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
n = 2;
d = Nest[Join @@ sierpinski /@ # &, {pts}, n];
list = Flatten[d, 1];
list = DeleteDuplicates[list];
point = RandomChoice[list];
next = Nearest[DeleteCases[list, point], point];
Graphics[{EdgeForm@Black, Polygon@d, Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[point], Blue, Point[next]}]
```

Comment: Why not try making it a graph?

Comment: @Wjx How would that solve the problem tho?

Comment: I've already got an elegant solution, I simply need a few coding time~

Comment: There's elegant mathematical property in this figure!

Comment: I think i got it.  `G = GraphData[{"Sierpinski", 3}];` and then walkers position is simply `n = VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[G, pos]];` so position = RandomChoice from that list

Comment: Yep, that's okay too, but will that be as speedy as my solution? I'm not sure.

Comment: Check that~I consider it as fairly a good solution!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, facinating question! Code first:

```
Clear["`*"];

n = 5;
steps = 1000;
dir = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};

start = FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ Transpose@Append[RandomChoice[dir, n - 1], RandomInteger[1, 2]];

move[pt_] :=With[{c = RandomChoice@Pick[-dir, BitAnd @@ (# + pt) & /@ -dir, 0]}, pt + c +RandomChoice@DeleteCases[dir, -c]];
move[{2^n, 0}] := {2^n - 1, RandomInteger@1};
move[{0, 2^n}] := {RandomInteger@1, 2^n - 1};
move[{0, 0}] := RandomChoice@Rest@dir;

ListLinePlot[{#1 + #2/2, #2*Sqrt@3/2} & @@@NestList[move, start, steps], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2^n}, {0, 2^n*Sqrt[3]/2}}, AspectRatio -> Sqrt[3]/2]
```

This code will generate the following figure:

[image: result]

Seemingly fit your requirement!

But how can this code be so elegant?(Well, is it?------Let me assume it is~) The key is how this pattern can be generated.

First is about points! Points, if exist on this figure, its base 2 expression of x and y coordinate after throw away the last digit must satisfy the following:

For one corresponding digit, there shouldn't be two 1s.

So the starting point could be determined.

Similarly, you can find the pattern of moving action------Simply calculate the mid point of the move and the rule will be the same!

So, the basic idea will be using BitAnd and a few simple list manipulation will do the rest!

Hope this can help~

---

## Add Method 2

```
n = 5;
steps = 10000;

G = GraphData[{"Sierpinski", n}];
start = RandomChoice@VertexList@G;
proc[pos_] := 
  RandomChoice@DeleteCases[VertexList@NeighborhoodGraph[G, pos], pos];
Nest[proc, start, steps]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This method can generate a result for n<6 because other wise the GraphData won't tell you the graph~

---

## Edit of Method 2

Try change this part:

```
DeleteCases[VertexList@NeighborhoodGraph[G, pos], pos]
```

to

```
VertexInComponents[G,pos,1]
```

Then it will be even faster than my first solution if n is small~

---

BTW: I checked about the efficiency of the two methods. The latter one takes much longer time(10*or even greater), I think that's because `NeighbourhoodGraph` is time consuming and Graph approch to this problem, afterall, is not that direct.

Comment: yeah, `Union[VertexInComponent[G, pos, 1], VertexOutComponent[G, pos, 1]];` returns identical results but much faster.

Comment: yep~That's even faster than my original solution!

Comment: I think just `VertexInComponent[G, pos, 1]` is enough but `Union[VertexInComponent[G, pos, 1], VertexOutComponent[G, pos, 1]]`,or maybe I miss something.

Comment: @yode Well, I didn't check this graph before I made the change. Apologize~ If this graph is without direction, yes, this will be enough.

Comment: A slight simplification: `ListLinePlot[NestList[move, start, steps].{{1, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}/2}/2^n, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}]`.

Comment: It's probably better to have you see for yourself: try running your code after running `SeedRandom["mse", Method -> "ExtendedCA"]`.

Comment: @J.M. I suppose that should be {{1,0},{1/2,Sqrt@3/2}}

Comment: It's the same matrix; you can check it if you want. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Oops, I missed that tiny /2